# The solutions are linearly independent and algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebra, grothendieck-topologies

The Grothendieck problem for differential equations (Grothendieck-Katz conjecture) is the following:

$$\alpha_n(x)y^{(n)}(x)+\dots +a_1 (x)y'(x)+a_0(x)y(x)=0, a_i \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\ \ \ \ (*)$$

We suppose that for almost each prime $p$, $(*)$, modulo $p$, has $n$ linearly independent solutions (powerseries in $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$, with field of constants $\mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$). Then $(*)$ has $n$ linearly independent solutions (powerseries in $\mathbb{C}((x))$ with field of constants $\mathbb{C}((x))$) and all are algebraic.

$$$$

Could you explain to me the above problem when we have for example the differential equation $xy'-ky=0, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

We have to find a prime such that for all primes $p$ greater or equal than that one, it stands that modulo $p$ the differential equation has in this case one solution in $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$.

Then the differential equation has one algebraic solution in $\mathbb{C}((x))$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a Laurent series $y=\sum_{-N}^\infty a_n x^n\in\mathbb{F}_p((x))$ which satisfies $xy'-ky=0$.  Then $na_n-ka_n=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for all $n$, so $a_n=0$ unless $n\equiv k$ mod $p$.  That is, the set of solutions consists exactly of series of the form $y=x^kf$, where $f\in \mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$.  So for all $p$, the space of solutions is one-dimensional over $\mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$.

Over $\mathbb{C}$, we have the same story: any solution $y=\sum a_n x^n$ must satisfy $na_n-ka_n=0$.  This time, the only way that can happen is if $a_n=0$ for all $n\neq k$, so the only solutions are $cx^k$ for $c\in\mathbb{C}$.  So, as expected, we have a one-dimensional space of solutions, and the solutions are algebraic.

Comment: Could you explain to me the last sentece of the first paragraph: "So for all $p$, the space of solutions is one-dimensional over $\mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$." ?

Comment: Well, by the previous sentence, $\{x^k\}$ is a basis over $\mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$ for the set of solutions.

Comment: Why is $\{x^k\}$ a basis over $\mathbb{F}_p((x^p))$ and not over $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$ ?

Comment: For instance, $x^{k+p}$ is also a solution.  More generally, a solution looks like $\sum_n a_{k+np} x^{k+np}=x^k\sum a_{k+np}(x^p)^n$, since $\sum a_nx^n$ is a solution iff $a_n=0$ for all $n$ such that $n\not\equiv k$ mod $p$.

Comment: So, the solution is the series $$\sum_n a_k x^k$$ We have that when $a_n \neq 0$ it has to be $n \equiv k \pmod p$, that means that $n=mp+k$, so $$\sum_n a_n x^n=\sum a_{mp+k}x^{mp+k}=\sum a_{mp+k}x^{np}x^k=\sum a_{mp+k}(x^p)^nx^k$$ since $x^p \equiv 1$ n $\mathbb{F}_p$ we have that the solution is $$\sum a_{mp+k}x^k$$ 

Have I understood it correctly? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: It is NOT true that $x^p=1$.  If you plug in any (nonzero) value $x=a$ for $a\in\mathbb{F}_p$, it is true that $a^p=a$, but elements of $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$ are just formal power series, not functions you're supposed to plug in values to.

Comment: So, the solution is the series $$\sum_{n=-N}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$ We have that when $a_n \neq 0$ it has to be $n \equiv k \pmod p$, that means that $n=mp+k$, so $$\sum_{n=-N}^{\infty} a_n x^n=\sum_{m=-\frac{N+k}{p}}^{\infty} a_{mp+k}x^{mp+k}=\sum_{m=-\frac{N+k}{p}}^{\infty} a_{mp+k}x^{mp}x^k=x^k\sum_{m=-\frac{N+k}{p}}^{\infty} a_{mp+k}(x^p)^m$$ 
Have I understood it correctly? 

But is the solution, $ \ \ \displaystyle{x^k\sum_{m=-\frac{N+k}{p}}^{\infty} a_{mp+k}(x^p)^m}$ a powerseries, or is only the coefficient of $x^k$ a powerseries?

Comment: They're both power series in $x$, but only the coefficient is a power series in $x^p$.

Comment: I see... To see if I have understood it correctly I applied it also to an other example.Suppose we have the differential equation:$$y'-y=0$$  The solution of the differential equation is $y=Ce^x$.Suppose we have a Laurent series $y=\sum_{-N}^\infty a_n x^n\in\mathbb{F}_p((x))$ which satisfies $y'-y=0$.  Then $$\sum_{-N}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}-\sum_{-N}^\infty a_n x^n=0 \Rightarrow \sum_{-N}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}-\sum_{-N}^\infty a_n x x^{n-1}=0\\ \Rightarrow \sum_{-N}^\infty (n-x)a_n x^{n-1}=0$$ So it must be $a_n=0$ for all $n$, in $\mathbb{F}_p((x))$ and in $\mathbb{C}((x))$. 

Is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30071/discussion-between-eric-wofsey-and-mary-star).